# Combine two single color images into one with CLI (imagemagick?)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, imagemagick, command-line-interface, imagemagick-convert

I'm generating "single" color images (B/W and red/white) of our todo schedule to write images to an 3-color e-ink screen, with my Raspberry Pi. First write the black one, then overwrite with red. This works really great, so no help required there.

But I would also like to have the same image available on a website. So I need to have my red image "overwrite" the black one, so I also have the black/red/white image the e-ink shows, as a png/bmp/jpg/whatever. For now we're just using the black one, but I want my overdue stuff in red as well.

I already have imagemagick for the conversions from SVG to PNG/BMP etc., and I'm guessing it should be able to do this. However, I could not find any examples. It's also hard to define the right search parameters, since a lot of people want to combine two images next to or below eachother, not actually combining them.

Does anyone here know how to do this? (I'm not stuck on ImageMagick, but that's the tool I already use)

My guess would be I'd need to make the white in the red/white transparent, then somehow layer it on top... But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to answers I found elsewhere on transparency, and above here from Bruce on 'composite', I ended up doing:

```
convert screen-output-red.png -fuzz 30% -transparent white -fill red -opaque black trans.png
composite trans.png screen-output.png combo.png
```

Haven't figured out if I could do it in one step, but this is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the RED image to 50% opacity

```
convert red.png -alpha set -background none -channel A -evaluate multiply 0.5 +channel red2.png
```

Then overlay the 50%RED on the black

```
convert black.png red2.png -gravity center -composite all.png
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this with ImageMagick. A very simple method is to make the white transparent then composite the red over the black.

```
magick img_black.png img_red.png -colorspace rgb \
   -fuzz "10%" -transparent white -background white -flatten result.png
```

First it reads in both images and sets the working colorspace to "rgb" so the result will be color instead of grayscale.

Then it sets a "-fuzz" value of "10%", which is the amount of variance from pure white that will be affected by the "-transparent" operation. You can adjust this amount to suit your needs.

Next the "-transparent white" operation removes all the white and near-white specified by the fuzz value. Since that removes the white from both images, we add a background color of white so the result will be flattened onto that.

Finish by flattening the red image onto the black image onto a white background and write the result to a file.

This command uses ImageMagick v7 on a *nix system. To use it with IMv6 change "magick" to "convert". To use this command in Windows change the continued-line backslash "\" to a caret "^".